# "He spends a lot of money buying a house" or "he spends a lot of money for buying a house"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> He spends a lot of money  buying a house

Or

> He spends a lot of money for buying a house?

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which one do **you** think is correct, and why?

Comment: Are you possibly trying to say, "he **spent** a lot of money buying a house"?

Comment: If using a preposition (you don't need one) it would more commonly be ***on*** *buying a house* or ***to buy*** *a house*.